# List of classifiers for Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, topolect, measure-word

There are many resources listing classifiers for Mandarin, but do any pages exist that document classifiers for Cantonese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [list of classifiers on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers) -- it notes that particular classifiers are Cantonese only, like *zam6* for smells, *bung6* for walls, *gaan1* for stores, *zoeng1* for chairs and so on.